# How to display a confirmation when the user clicks on submit button of the form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, actionmailer

I am newbie to this language so forgive me if this wastes your time. The code below should display **"Message was successfully sent"** after the user has finished submitting the queries. It is not working as expected. Thanks

```
flash.now.notice= "Message was successfully sent."
```

Comment: Are you using `flash.now` knowing the difference with basic `flash` ?

Comment: actually, frankly speaking I am not aware of the differences between `flash.now` and basic `flash`. Do you mind to spare some thoughts and enlighten me?

Comment: You can check http://goo.gl/w3QNt and http://goo.gl/dC36h . Basically, Flash is available for the next request while flash.now is available for the current request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash` is a hash, try `flash[:notice] = "mesage"`.

Then:

```
# on whichever template you want to render the flash messages, 
# most likely on layouts/application.html.erb
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry, where does the `if statement` go to. (layout.haml ??) ?

Comment: edited, and that was [HAML](http://haml.info/), a templating engine like ERB (but better :D).

Comment: your answer may be correct, at them moment, it is just displaying the message regardless of the whether messages has been sent or not. will continue tomorrow (too late in the night now) and definitely accept it if it works and i think it will work :)

Comment: works! cheers [[if possible could you please vote up my question ;) ? ]]